# How can I suppress and capture knitr chunk ouput?

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

In a `knitr` document, I am calling an external code chunk which generates a `ggplot2` object similar to the following:

```
# file.R
# ---- create_plot ----
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + geom_point()
gg
```

In my document (Flexdashboard Rmd, specifically):

````
# dashboard.Rmd
```{r setup}
knitr::read_chunk("plot.R")
```

```{r create_plot}
```
````

I would like to call this chunk and suppress the printing of the `gg` object, allowing me to do some tweaks to the object (title, colors, etc.) and display the plot later in my document. I've tried `results='hide'` when calling the chunk with no success. My desired document would be something like:

````
# dashboard.Rmd
```{r setup}
knitr::read_chunk("plot.R")
```

```{r create_plot, results='hide'}
```

```{r display_plot}
gg <- gg + labs(title = "Custom title")
gg
```
````

Is this possible without editing the external chunk to omit the final `gg` call?

Comment: Have you tried `include = FALSE` as a chunk option?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `gg` statement from the chunk, making it create the plot, not create and print?

Comment: That was the trick! Thanks @RyanMorton! Would you please submit as an answer so that I can accept and credit you?

Comment: If you create a function to define the object with ggplot, then you can create parameters within the knitr document at any point prior to plotting and cache them Then feed them in as arguments to your own ggplotting function , and then tell it to draw the created object with your current variables at will.

Comment: @DavidF.Severski, sure! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to include = FALSE in the chunk option.  This way, the code will run but not be included. I often do this when I run batch code using source(). Anyhow, give this a try:

````
```{r display_plot, include = FALSE}
gg <- gg + labs(title = "Custom title")
gg
```
````